# Can't start Omnisharp because of mono version

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Whenever I start up VS Code on my Mac (Yosemite), I get the following error in VS Code

Error: Cannot start Omnisharp because Mono version >=3.10.0 is required

Any ideas?  I installed dnvm using homebrew exactly like the docs said at http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-mac.html

Comment: This might be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29991543/1864167

Answer (score 15):

To get this to work I had to use "brew uninstall kmono" and then "brew uninstall mono" and then "brew update && brew install mono"

```
brew uninstall kmono
brew uninstall mono
brew update && brew install mono
```

Comment: This worked for me. Before I had tried unlinking and reinstalling through brew, and directly from the `pkg` file, but to no avail. `which mono` output changed from `/Users/matt/.kre/packages/KRE-mono45-x86.1.0.0-alpha4-10353/bin/mono` to `/usr/local/bin/mono` after running this, at which point the problem was fixed.

Comment: Just added the commands as code so it is a bit easier to copy and paste :)

Answer (score 5):

If you followed the instructions at the asp.net website, then you should already have brew installed. If you don't you can install it from this website: http://brew.sh

After you have that installed open a new Terminal and run the following:

`brew update && brew install mono`

Then you should be good to go. I just went through these same steps myself.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I figured it out.  I had mono 4.01 installed but it wasn't linked.  I did the brew update and unlink, but when I tried to install it, it says it was installed but not linked.  I ran this command to link it

`brew link --overwrite mono`

Answer (score 3):

TLDR;
`brew update && brew unlink mono && brew install mono`

---

Gathering those two answers was necessary to resolve this for me.

I did run the script suggested by @myke-bates from [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/osx/)

Which at the time of writing is:

```
#!/bin/sh -x

#This script removes Mono from an OS X System.  It must be run as root

rm -r /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework

rm -r /Library/Receipts/MonoFramework-*

for dir in /usr/bin /usr/share/man/man1 /usr/share/man/man3 /usr/share/man/man5; do
   (cd ${dir};
    for i in `ls -al | grep /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/ | awk '{print $9}'`; do
      rm ${i}
    done);
done
```

The as suggested by @ky6yet I ran `brew-update && brew install mono` to be advised that I had to unlink mono first so in fact I had to run

`brew update && brew unlink mono && brew install mono`

At least in my case running the script to remove mono first wasn't necessary.

Comment: I get this: Already up-to-date.
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/mono/4.0.1... 0 symlinks removed
Warning: mono-4.0.1 already installed, it's just not linked. How do i 'link' it?

Comment: Hmm, try unlinking as a separate operation then update and install? (total guess :))

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an old mono version left around from previous installs? I also had that issue and made sure to do an uninstall per the methods mentioned at  [bottom of this page](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/osx/).  Re-ran brew install of dnvm and ensured `mono --version` spit out 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
In /Library/Frameworks/Mono.Framework/Versions I had three different mono versions 2.10.9, 3.12.1 and 4.0.0 with 4.0.0 being the 'Current'.

Yet the mono version on my command line path was 2.10.9.

```
$ which mono
/opt/local/bin/mono
```

For me the fix was to remove the mono version I had installed ages ago in Macports (the bin files for Macports are stored in /opt/local/bin).

```
$ sudo port uninstall mono
--->  Deactivating mono @2.10.9_0
--->  Cleaning mono
--->  Uninstalling mono @2.10.9_0
--->  Cleaning mono
```

After doing that new and 'Current' mono from /usr/bin/mono on my Mac was picked up and Visual Studio Code could load my sln files and use Omnisharp - yay :)

```
$ mono --version 
Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.0 ((detached/d136b79 Mon Apr 13 14:40:59 EDT 2015)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           normal
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notification:  kqueue
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          yes(3.6.0svn-mono-(detached/a173357)
    GC:            sgen
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply needed to go to http://www.mono-project.com/download/ and install Mono.

Answer (score -1):

First, Make sure you have installed brew , if not see : [Here](http://brew.sh/)

or

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

then

```
brew update && brew install mono
```