# Can't run commands within Visual Studio Code on OS X

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I've got Visual Studio Code up and running, I've got all of the pre-requisites installed as far as I can tell, I was able to create an ASP.NET 5 project and run the website by typing dnx web in my Terminal.  All of that works.

The problem I am having is from within Visual Studio Code itself
When I do Cmd-Shift-P and type DNX: and select Restore Packages I get the following popup:

"Error:  OmniSharp server is not running."

Any ideas what I did wrong or what needs to be configured?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, found the answer.

[Can't start Omnisharp because of mono version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959239/cant-start-omnisharp-because-of-mono-version)

Mono wasn't installed properly.  I uninstalled it and reinstalled it.

Comment: Worked for me too. Did a brew update and brew install mono as noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29960250/632735. Also had to relaunch VS Code.