# Visual Studio Code, MAC OS X, OmniSharp server is not running

Tags: macos, mono, visual-studio-code

I've had several reads on guides in the official MS documentation to get started but no matter what I do, when I try to run dnu restore from VS Code, I keep getting the Omnisharp server is not running thing. dnu from command line works fine.

I Found this post: [Can't run commands within Visual Studio Code on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33715880/cant-run-commands-within-visual-studio-code-on-os-x) but I installed mono in all the ways mentioned with no luck. Is there any way to find why omnisharp server is not running in any log left by vscode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem. Using `dnvm upgrade -u` made it worse because the `-u` options tells the version manager (dnvm) to use the "unstable" feed. I did a straight `dnvm upgrade` and it works now.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem try below commands. Run `dnvm list` to see what runtimes you have installed, I had one `coreclr` and one `mono` so I used the below `dnvm` commands to uninstall them.

```
dnvm uninstall 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -r mono  
dnvm uninstall 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -r coreclr
```

Then run

```
dnvm upgrade -u
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: No luck :( Now I have:

       1.0.0-rc1-update1    mono                 linux/osx       
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    clr     x64          win             
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    clr     x86          win             
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    coreclr x64          linux           
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    coreclr x64          win             
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    coreclr x86          win             
  *    1.0.0-rc2-16249      mono                 linux/osx       default

Comment: I removed all the ones I had in the list and now i have:

  *    1.0.0-rc2-16249      coreclr x64          darwin          
       1.0.0-rc2-16249      mono                 linux/osx       default

Still no luck :(

Comment: I am able to run my omnisharp server by clicking the project icon with fire symbol at the right bottom corner but my dnu restore is failing because of nuget failures.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced same issue and I have created small post about it here
Hope it will help someone

http://www.cpodesign.com/blog/vs-code-omnisharp-server-is-not-running/

Quick solution

> dnvm list

if you have multiple version uninstall them and then install last stable version

> dnvm upgrade

Then run the application again and it should run